# Is it possible to upgrade the edition of a GCP Cloud Sql Server Express instance?

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, upgrade, google-cloud-sql

I have a number of GCP Cloud Sql SQL EXPRESS 2017 instances that I'd like to upgrade to standard editions. Ive considered just spinning up a standard edition instance and migrating, but GCP's naming conventions make this impractical as you cant reuse the same name. It doesn't look like theres any way to upgrade the edition of an instance, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

After trying to do this my self with a test instance, it looks like there is no way to do this, you would need to export your databases and import them into another instance with the needed version in order to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out, migration it is

Answer (score 1):

In-place upgrade of major version and/or edition is in preview: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/upgrade-major-db-version-inplace